# Ajax File Uploader not working in IE9

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have ajax file uploader in my MVC3 application it's working absolutely fine in Firefox and chrome but it's not working in IE9 and IE8. when i have upload the file  it give me wrong file name at server side in IE.

here is my up-loader code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitializeUploader() {
            Dname = [];
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                multiple: true,
                element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
                action: '@Url.Action("UploadDocument","Project")',
                debug: true,
                params: { id: $("#Id").val() },
                onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
                },

                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    alert(responseJSON.fileName);
                    $("#DocumentName").val(responseJSON.fileName);
                    fileSize = responseJSON.size;
                    Dname.push(responseJSON.fileName);
                    type = responseJSON.type;
                }

            });
        }  

</script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" style="margin-left: 4px;
            margin-top: 0px;" id="documentUploadForm">
            <div id="file-uploader">
                <input type="file" id="uplodfile" />
                <input class="button" type="button" value="Upload" id="UploadDocbtn" style="float: right;
                    width: 100px;" /></div>
            </form>
```

server side Action

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UploadDocument(string qqfile, int id)
  {

     // code for saving File 
  }
```

when i have run this in IE instead of giving file name in **qqfile** parameter, it give me file like **System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper** and file is also not save properly.
i am not getting is this browser issue or IE prevent Some script.
so how i can save file using ajax file up loader in IE?

Comment: instead of using `string qqfile` use `HttpPostedFileWrapper qqfile` in your controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, IE looks to be working exactly like it should. 
And instead of `UploadDocument(string qqfile, int id)` you should have `UploadDocument(HttpPostedFileWrapper qqfile, int id)`
 File should be saved as `qqfile.SaveAs("path to file")`

Not clear what file name are you getting now. Possibly that is a result of conversion [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679926.aspx) to string and IE does not return some info required for that conversion to return file name instead of original object type. 
Try to do something like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UploadDocument(System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper qqfile, int id)
  {
     qqfile.SaveAs("filename");
     // code for saving File 
  }
```

It should work just fine in all browsers

Comment: it's not working in mozila it give null value for System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper qqfile when i have upload a file.please let me know how i can do with mozila?

Comment: See if there are any errors in firebug. And check network tab - does it pass any files to server?

Comment: Also - what exact plugin are you using?

Comment: I have qq file up-loader,and it not showing me any error in firebug.

Comment: I would try to change `qqfile` to `uplodfile` OR add a setting to qq.FileUploader: qqfilename:'qqfile'

Comment: I have tried that also still it give me the same error if i put HttpPostedFileWrapper in parameter it work fine in IE not it's not work in mozila.